# Horizontal ListView builder end with one button using row

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-listview

I need horizontal list view (ListView.builder) with scrollable and these list end with one button, I am using row but screen cannot able to scroll

I am newbie in flutter.

[image]

```
Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            SizedBox(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/2,
                child: ListView.builder(
                  physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  itemCount: newList!.content.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => Column(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        padding: newList!.content.length == index
                            ? EdgeInsets.only(right: 13)
                            : 0 == index
                                ? EdgeInsets.only(left: 13, right: 13)
                                : EdgeInsets.only(right: 13),
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            Column(
                              children: [
                                ImageCard(
                                    contentItem: newList.content[index],
                                  
                                    isInINR: newList.isInINR)
                              ],
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                )),
          ],
        ),
```

Comment: Hey, I think better to attach your code instead of an image.

Comment: Hi @DewaPrabawa in these code I done with listview builder with horizontal scroll but i need after the listview i need view all button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of adding new element in list you add the condition like below. If index is last then you can show the view all button. I hope you will get the answer. You can ask more if you have any queries.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
    theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
    scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue,
  ),
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  home: Scaffold(
    body: Center(
      child: MyWidget(),
      ),
    ),
  );
 } 
}
class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
bool displayAllList = false;
int minimumCount = 4;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

List list = List.generate(8, (index) => index).toList();
return ListView.builder(
  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          const SizedBox(
              width: 50, height: 50, child: ColoredBox(color: Colors.red)),
          if ((list.length > minimumCount && (index == minimumCount - 1)) && (list.length > 4 && displayAllList == false)) ...[
            TextButton(onPressed: () {
              setState((){
                displayAllList = true;
              });
            }, child: Text('View All'))
          ]
        ],
      ),
    );
  },
  itemCount: (list.length > 4 && displayAllList == false) ? 4 : list.length,
);
}
}
```

Comment: Hi @Mayur Patel I have one doubt. In my case list length has 10 data but I need to show four data then click view all show all data. I am using clamp method in item count show 4 data but in our condition, how can show the view all button after the 4th data. can you help me?

Comment: can you please help these issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76720350/zigzag-container-design-in-flutter

Answer (score 1):

to add a widget to the end of listView.builder in flutter, you can check the current index, if index is the last item index, we realize that listView has built all the items and we can add a widget to the end of list,also we need to increase listCount, here is a simple:

```
SizedBox(
                        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2,
                        child: ListView.builder(
                          physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                          itemCount: newList!.content.length + 1,
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                              index == newList!.content.length
                                  ? TextButton()
                                  : YourListItemWidget(),
                        )),
```